# update file in photoshop

Tags: file, photoshop

I have opened a file (image) in PhotoShop, but the file on the disk keeps changing. Think of that I am replacing my file on the disk, with another image (but keeping the file name the same), and then how do I make Photoshop see the new updated image.
The only way that I find to do it is to go into File-->Open again, and it warns me that the file on the disk has changed, do I want to continue...
So, is there a shortcut to do this (e.g. something like F5 for web-browsers)?

Answer (score 6):

F12 should do the job for you.

Comment: F12 is grayed out, and nothing happens when I press F12

Comment: @user2112840 Which OS and version of Photoshop you have? Try to go to Edit->Keyboard Shortcuts->File tab->Revert. I have it on F12 check you system settings (Revert will only work if you apply some changes to the image first. Follow the process - open image->replace the image on hard drive->do some changes to the image in Photoshop->use Revert tool)

Comment: Revert only works if you changed the image in photoshop, not externally which is what the OP wants.